# Ranorex MvvmCross MvxColor Plugin crash

Tags: ios, mvvmcross, ranorex

In our iOS (xamarin) project with the new MvvmCross version 4.0 the MvxColor plugin is crashing all the time when we execute our test with Ranorex, our UI Automation Tool.
This is the exception on the log:

```
MwmCross Plugins Color iOS MvxlosColor_ToNative MwmCross_Platform Ul MvxColor 
MwmCross Plugins Color_MvxColorValueConverter_Convert_object System Type object System Globalization Culturelnfo + 230
MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep ApplyValueConverterSourceToTarget_object + 490
MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep ConvertSourceToTarget object + 260
MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep GetValue + 180
```

Somebody has an idea on why this is happening? Running the app normally has no problems at all.

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

Thanks for the reply. Here a peace of the log that is repeated in all the file:

```
    iPad 16:21 70%I I, Alb■ 
Ranorex Services - Log 
Auto Refresh 
Auto Scroll 
Refresh 
CV 10/VC/lie 10...IV.04.V II 1-/V1.11.1y. 17.1 lb GIIIVC 1,11 /V b,1 
2016/02/02 15:31:05:039 Debug: BGT is alive (1200 s) 2016/02/02 15:31:10:359 Error: Application 'com.example.app' logged: 'Application crashed with SIGSEGV 
"4 BSC Ox000000010219b008 MwmCross Plugins Color iOS MvxlosColor_ToNative MwmCross_Platform Ul MvxColor + 120", "5 BSC Ox0000000101838508 MwmCross Plugins Color_MvxColorValueConverter_Convert_object System Type object System Globalization Culturelnfo + 230, "6 BSC Ox0000000100ca321 c MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep ApplyValueConverterSourceToTarget_object + 490, "7 BSC 0x0000000100ca3664 MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep ConvertSourceToTarget object + 260", "8 BSC Ox0000000100ca3f94 MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep GetValue + 180" 2016/02/02 15:31:10:845 Info: Received request: rxsa:// 2016/02/02 15:31:10:854 Info: Sucessfully handled request: 'rxsa://' 2016/02/02 15:31:13:355 Debug: AppStatusEvents set to 1' 2016/02/02 15:31:23:356 Debug: AppStatusEvents set to '0' 2016/02/02 15:31:35:185 Debug: BGT is alive (1230 s) 2016/02/02 15:32:05:315 Debug: BGT is alive (1260 s) 2016/02/02 15:32:35:449 Debug: BGT is alive (1290 s) 2016/02/02 15:33:05:578 Debug: BGT is alive (1320 s) 2016/02/02 15:33:35:707 Debug: BGT is alive (1350 s) 2016/02/02 15:34:05:840 Debug: BGT is alive (1380 s) 2016/02/02 15:34:32:794 Error: Application 'com.example.app' logged: 'Application crashed with SIGSEGV 
"4 BSC Ox0000000102177008 MwmCross Plugins Color i0S_MvxlosColor ToNative MwmCross Platform Ul MvxColor + 120", "5 BSC Ox0000000101814508 MwmCross Plugins Color_MvxColorValueConverter_Convert_object System Type object System Globalization CultureInfo + 230, "6 BSC Ox0000000100c7f21 c MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep ApplyValueConverterSourceToTarget_object + 490, "7 BSC 0x0000000100c7f664 MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep ConvertSourceToTarget object + 260W, "8 BSC 0x0000000100c7ff94 MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep GetValue + 180" 
2016/02/02 15:34:33:306 Info: Received request: rxsa:// 2016/02/02 15:34:33:313 Info: Sucessfully handled request: 'rxsa://' 2016/02/02 15:34:35:814 Debug: AppStatusEvents set to 1' 2016/02/02 15:34:35:980 Debug: BGT is alive (1410 s) 2016/02/02 15:34:45:816 Debug: AppStatusEvents set to '0' 2016/02/02 15:35:06:110 Debug: BGT is alive (1440 s) 2016/02/02 15:35:36:249 Debug: BGT is alive (1470 s) 2016/02/02 15:35:36:447 Error: Application 'com.example.app' logged: 'Application crashed with SIGSEGV 
"4 BSC Ox0000000102153008 MwmCross Plugins Color iOS MvxlosColor ToNative MwmCross_Platform Ul MvxColor + 120", "5 BSC Ox00000001017f0508 MwmCross Plugins Color MvxColorValueConverter_Convert_object System Type object System Globalization Culturelnfo + 230, "6 BSC Ox0000000100c5b21 c MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep ApplyValueConverterSourceToTarget object + 490, "7 BSC 0x0000000100c5b664 MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep ConvertSourceToTarget object + 260", "8 BSC Ox0000000100c5bf94 MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep GetValue + 180" 2016/02/02 15:35:36:923 Info: Received request: rxsa:// 2016/02/02 15:35:36:934 Info: Sucessfully handled request: 'rxsa://' 2016/02/02 15:35:39:436 Debug: AppStatusEvents set to 1' 2016/02/02 15:35:49:437 Debug: AppStatusEvents set to '0' 2016/02/02 15:36:06:380 Debug: BGT is alive (1500 s) 2016/02/02 15:36:36:508 Debug: BGT is alive (1530 s) 2016/02/02 15:37:06:653 Debug: BGT is alive (1560 s) 2016/02/02 15:37:36:780 Debug: BGT is alive (1590 s) 2016/02/02 15:38:06:920 Debug: BGT is alive (1620 s) 2016/02/02 15:38:37:052 Debug: BGT is alive (1650 s) 2016/02/02 15:39:07:191 Debug: BGT is alive (1680 s) 2016/02/02 15:39:37:330 Debug: BGT is alive (1710 s) 2016/02/02 15:40:07:468 Debug: BGT is alive (1740 s) 2016/02/02 15:40:37:599 Debug: BGT is alive (1770 s) 2016/02/02 15:41:07:683 Debug: BGT is alive (1800 s) 2016/02/02 15:41:37:837 Debug: BGT is alive (1830 s) 2016/02/02 15:42:00:973 Error: Application 'com.example.app' logged: 'Application crashed with SIGSEGV 
"4 BSC Ox0000000102143008 MwmCross Plugins Color iOS MvxlosColor ToNative MwmCross_Platform Ul MvxColor + 120", "5 BSC Ox00000001017e0508 MwmCross Plugins Color_MvxColorValueConverter Convert_object System Type object System Globalization Culturelnfo + 230, "6 BSC Ox0000000100c4b21 c MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep ApplyValueConverterSourceToTarget object + 490, "7 BSC 0x0000000100c4b664 MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep ConvertSourceToTarget object + 260", "8 BSC Ox0000000100c4bf94 MwmCross Binding Bindings SourceSteps MvxSourceStep GetValue + 180" 2016/02/02 15:42:01:472 Info: Received request: rxsa:// 2016/02/02 15:42:01:482 Info: Sucessfully handled request: 'rxsa://' 2016/02/02 15:42:03:984 Debug: AppStatusEvents set to 1' 2016/02/02 15:42:07:964 Debug: BGT is alive (1860 s) 2016/02/02 15:42:13:984 Debug: AppStatusEvents set to '0'
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's kind of hard to find anything in that error log. Do you have more information?

Comment: Does it work with Xamarin.UITest?

Comment: Also a reproducible sample for a minimal application that emits this behavior would be helpful. The only thing that could go wrong is if MvxColor is null. That should however throw a null reference exception. Maybe this is a linker issue where MvxColor, since it might not be used directly anywhere i stripped out by the linker, depending on if this is a debug build or not.

Comment: I will try to see if the color is linked correctly in the main app. Thanks for the help.